# What does the the `server_name` of the server should set when the API base is ip address?

Tags: nginx

What does the the `server_name` of the server should set when the API base is ip address?

```
server {

    listen 8000;
    server_name `what there should set`;

    access_log /data/ldl/logs/13.20.32.76.access.log  main;

    location /index01.html {
        alias /data/repo/Qi02/index01.html;
    }
```

My API address base is `13.20.32.76`, can I set the `server_name` to ip address?

I mean, such as I have a API, one of the API is like this: `http://13.20.32.76:8000/api/users/list/`

what does the `server_name` should write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use IP address as server name, you can refer to the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html). Actually there is quite a lot of things you can do with the server name directive.

> If someone makes a request using an IP address instead of a server name, the “Host” request header field will contain the IP address and the request can be handled using the IP address as the server name:

```
server {
    listen       80;    server_name  example.org
                 www.example.org
                 ""
                 192.168.1.1
                 ;
    ...
}
```